# rails attachment_fu public_filename problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment-fu

attachment_fu generates wrong public_filename.

```
>> pic.thumbnails
=> ProductPicture id: 12331, product_id: nil, parent_id: 12330, content_type: "image/png", filename: "b_9788994035109_mid.png", thumbnail: "mid", size: 16562, width: 205, height: 205, created_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50", updated_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50", 
ProductPicture id: 12332, product_id: nil, parent_id: 12330, content_type: "image/png", filename: "b_9788994035109_thumb.png", thumbnail: "thumb", size: 2300, width: 52, height: 52, created_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:51", updated_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:51"
>> pic
ProductPicture id: 12330, product_id: 23236, parent_id: nil, content_type: "image/gif", filename: "b_9788994035109.gif", thumbnail: nil, size: 73990, width: 400, height: 400, created_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50", updated_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50"
>> pic.thumbnails
=> ProductPicture id: 12331, product_id: nil, parent_id: 12330, content_type: "image/png", filename: "b_9788994035109_mid.png", thumbnail: "mid", size: 16562, width: 205, height: 205, created_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50", updated_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:50", ProductPicture id: 12332, product_id: nil, parent_id: 12330, content_type: "image/png", filename: "b_9788994035109_thumb.png", thumbnail: "thumb", size: 2300, width: 52, height: 52, created_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:51", updated_at: "2009-10-05 02:43:51"
>> pic.public_filename
=> "/product_pictures/0001/2330/b_9788994035109.gif"
>> pic.public_filename(:mid)
=> "/product_pictures/0001/2330/b_9788994035109_mid.gif"
```

It generates ".gif" instead of ".png" when the actual type is '.png' (gif is the parent's type)

This works ok with my dev machine but not with my production machine.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I didn't specify :processor in attachment_fu and it uses any processor installed.
My dev machine has ImageScience and RMagick and my production machine had only RMagick.
ImageScience resizes gif to png as it can't handle gif very well.